# ElasticSearch - pagination of date histogram results

Tags: date, pagination, elasticsearch, histogram

Is it possible to paginate results from a date histogram?

I have the following example date histogram, but using the  "from" : 0, "size" : 10 parameters do not seem to work.

```
POST _search/
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "facets" : {
        "histo1" : {                
            "date_histogram" : {
                "value_field": "value.count", 
                "interval" : "10s",
                "field": "_timestamp"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "from" and "size" parameters work only with results of your query (hits). Facets run on the entire result list regardless of how many records you choose to retrieve. Therefore, in order to implement "pagination" on histogram, you need to limit your query. For example, in order to retrieve all histogram buckets for the last hour you can simply add range query or filter to you query that will limit results to the current hour. If `_timestamp` is indexed as date, you can do something like this:

```
POST _search/
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "range" : {
                    "_timestamp" : {
                        "gt": "now-1h",
                        "lte": "now"
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    },
    "facets" : {
        "histo1" : {                
            "date_histogram" : {
                "value_field": "value.count", 
                "interval" : "10s",
                "field": "_timestamp"
            }
        }
    }
}
```